# Footer Overlapping Dynamically Generated Table

Tags: html, asp.net, footer

On an aspx page I am working on, a table is being generated server-side, and looks fine on the page. Also, on this page, there is a small footer. The end result is that when the content in the table gets long enough, the table extends past the footer, but the footer does not re-position itself at the bottom of the table. What kind of css magic do I need to add to the style of either the div surrounding the table or the  around the footer to make things work?

Here is some of the offending code:

```
<div id="contentPlusFooter">
                <div id="content" class="ContentWidth">
                    <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
                        <div id="contentBanner" class="insideContentWidth">
                            <span class="contentBannerTitle">Inventory Tracking Report:</span>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptInventory" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvInventory" runat="server" CssClass="insideContentWidth" GridLines="None"
                                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20"
                                    EmptyDataText="No inventory items found">
                                    <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altRowStyle" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="tableHeader" HorizontalAlign="left" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MinInventoryLevel" HeaderText="Minimum Inventory Level"
                                            SortExpression="MinInventoryLevel" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentInventoryLevel" HeaderText="Current Inventory Level"
                                            SortExpression="CurrentInventoryLevel" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Inventory Start Date" SortExpression="InventoryStartDate">
                                            <ItemTemplate>

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <br />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <rw:adminfooter id="Footer" runat="server" />
            </div>
```

Comment: What versions of what browsers did you test this in?

Comment: The application is currently only tested in IE7, so none of the other browsers matter. (If it were up to me, this would not be the case, but what can you do...)

Comment: We'll also need the relevant CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap your header, content and footer in a 3 row table.

Comment: Well, tried the 3 row table, and it didn't work. Instead, the footer overlaps the content and also prevents any content that extends below it from being shown. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You probably have a floating div defined in your CSS then.

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but I just moved the footer up into the main content div. Kind of a hack, but it looks fine and the functionality is preserved. Sometimes fighting with css just isn't worth the time...